# PJSIP How to forward all the SIP headers as received in incoming call

Tags: asterisk

I am running an Asterisk 20.03 SIP server. I receive multiple X Headers in the incoming SIP INVITE, and I want to send all these SIP headers when I forward this INVITE to the connected SIP client.

I did try below configuration:

```
; extensions.conf

[default]
exten => 1234,1,Set(X-My-ID = ${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-ID)})
exten => 1234,1,Set(X-My-Loc = ${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-Loc)})
exten => 1234,1,Set(X-My-Add = ${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-Add)})
exten => 1234,1,Dial(PJSIP/1234,10)
```

But I don't see the SIP headers getting added in the INVITE to SIP client.

I want to forward all these SIP headers received in the INVITE, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just setting the value of a variable with these lines:

```
exten => 1234,1,Set(X-My-ID = ${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-ID)})
exten => 1234,1,Set(X-My-Loc = ${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-Loc)})
exten => 1234,1,Set(X-My-Add = ${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-Add)})
```

You're also not incrementing the priority so none of those lines will get executed anyway.

I think this should do what you're looking for:

```
[headers]
exten => add,1,Set(PJSIP_HEADER(add,X-My-ID)=${MyID})
 same => n,Set(PJSIP_HEADER(add,X-My-Loc)=${MyLoc})
 same => n,Set(PJSIP_HEADER(add,X-My-Add)=${MyAdd})

[default]
exten => 1234,1,Set(_MyID=${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-ID)})
 same => n,Set(_MyLoc=${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-Loc)})
 same => n,Set(_MyAdd=${PJSIP_HEADER(read,X-My-Add)})
 same => n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},10,b(headers^add^1))
```

This sets the value of channel variables with the header values, and then [the `Dial` command](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+20+Application_Dial) calls another context to add these values in to the headers. See [a similar question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1079151/forwarding-sip-headers-with-asterisk-pjsip) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, when I try the configuration I am getting error `parse_options: Unrecognized option: '^'`

Comment: Sorry, typo in the Dial command is fixed now